# Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Tags: запятая

1. Он домой(,) озябший(,) вернётся.
2. Дарю тебе сердца моего(,) любящего(,) нежность.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказал, что в первом предложении обособление возможно. То, что называется "авторская пунктуация". Во втором — нет.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые не нужны, в обоих предложениях используется инверсия и определенное актуальное членение.

1) "Домой он озЯбший вернется". Исходный вариант: Домой он  вернется озябший. Вернется озябший - составное именное сказуемое, вернется - знаменательная связка со значением движения. Инверсия позволяет логически выделить слово "озябший".

Вариант с обособлением: Озябший, он наконец вернется домой. Мы видим, что при распространении предложения появляется возможность обособить прилагательное, которое раньше входило в состав сказуемого.

2) "Дарю тебе сЕрдца моего любящего нежность". Здесь также инверсия. Исходный вариант: Дарю тебе нежность моего любящего сердца. Инверсия позволяет логически выделить сочетание "сЕрдца моего любящего".

Answer (score 1):

> *Нужны ли здесь запятые?*

**Всем рулит контекст. См.:**

Каким он вернётся домой?

*-- Он домой озябший вернётся.*

Куда он направится, если озябнет? Пойдёт ли по …?

*-- Нет. Он домой, озябший, вернётся.*

Вернётся ли он домой, если озябнет?

*-- Конечно. Он домой, озябший, (обязательно) вернётся.*

Comment: Slava, это же явно стихотворный текст. Попробуйте его продолжить в обособленном варианте. (В этом случае ударение падает на глагол "вернется").

Comment: Slava, это же явно стихотворный текст. Попробуйте его продолжить в обособленном варианте. В этом случае ударение падает на  "вернется", и глагольную тему придется продолжить: не останется на улице, не пойдет в гости и т.д.

Comment: Vera:  "Slava, это же явно стихотворный текст".=== НУ И ЧТО ? Вы же контекста этого "стихотворного текста" не знаете,  но тем не менее пытаетесь ссылаться при обосновании ненужности запятой на АКТУАЛЬНОЕ ЧЛЕНЕНИЕ. 

А АЧ-ТО КАК РАЗ И ВОЗМОЖНО ЛИШЬ ПРИ ЗНАНИИ КОНТЕКСТА.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, если рассматривать "озябший" в качестве причастия, то нужно обособление. Если же - это прилагательное, то обособление не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь: "если определение оторвано в тексте от определяемого существительного, например: Глаза смыкались и, полузакрытые, тоже улыбались (Тургенев)".

Поэтому надо обособить.